# SparkR DataFrame support for UTF-8 characters (multiple language support)

Tags: r, character-encoding, apache-spark, locale, sparkr

I have verified using Scala that a dataframe contains non-ascii UTF-8 characters using `df.show()`. Spark-SQL also shows the correct encoding.

However, when I try showDF(df) using SparkR, the UTF-8 characters don't show properly. How do we get showDF(df) to show UTF-8 characters to show up?

Initially `LOCALE=""` & `LANG="en_US.UTF-8"`...

1) Set it to `LANG="xx_XX.UTF-8"` where X is appropriate language identifier

2) `Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL",locale="xx_XX.UTF-8")`
but showDF() still didn't show characters in the native language

Comment: What's your `LOCALE` and `LANG`?

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.

1) Run `locale -a` to find out which locales are generated on your system

`C
C.UTF-8
POSIX
en_US.utf8`

Indicates ASCII character encoding and English UTF-8 are available.

2) Generate the desired locale for your language. In order to find out what the locale is for your operating system, you need to search for the i18n list of supported languages/encoding (For Ubuntu it's located at `/usr/share/i18n/SUPPORTED`)

Once you find the encoding, run `sudo locale-gen ru_RU.UTF-8`

3) You can then set the `LANG` environment variable. For bash, `export LANG="ru_RU"`

4) Run `R` from your terminal and you should see a prompt in your target language.

```
R version 3.1.1 (2014-07-10) -- "Sock it to Me"
Copyright (C) 2014 The R Foundation for Statistical Computing
Platform: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu (64-bit)

R -- это свободное ПО, и оно поставляется безо всяких гарантий.
Вы вольны распространять его при соблюдении некоторых условий.
Введите 'license()' для получения более подробной информации.

R -- это проект, в котором сотрудничает множество разработчиков.
Введите 'contributors()' для получения дополнительной информации и
'citation()' для ознакомления с правилами упоминания R и его пакетов
в публикациях.

Введите 'demo()' для запуска демонстрационных программ, 'help()' -- для
```

Alternatively, you can enter an error expression to see what language is the error prompted with.